# Elfinder file upload throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor, elfinder

Im using Laravel 5 with CKEditor and ElFinder.

Ive added

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/elfinder/ckeditor';
```

to editor.config in ckeditor/config.js. Ive got the upload tab, but when I add an image and click Send to Server I get the exception:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207
```

which normally gets tossed when the route verb is incorrect (GET rather then POST or something like that). Is there another setting I need to enact in elfinder config?

Console debug is throwing a 500 error on this url thats being called:

http://main.local/elfinder/ckeditor?CKEditor=description&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I switched over to ckFinder. It was a lot easier to setup and seemed to have a little better support.

Comment: use 
http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/ - you can grab the latest ckeditor with the old fckeditor provided at the tutorial site